# Is there any way for an App.config file to reference another full config file? (.NET)

Tags: .net, app-config

**Update: this question, including the title, was rephrased, see history for details**

I know that the following App.config includes a external file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings configSource="appSettings.config"/>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="50"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

But I don't know how to move the system.net to the second file. Actually I haven't tried it, but I am almost certain that it will not work, and I want to know if there is an way for an App.config to include another App.config file by reference.

Comment: Why would you split the config into 2 files instead of one then?

Comment: Because one is for the library and the other is for the project that uses the library.

Comment: dll share the apps .config, why do you need the system.net section in another file?

Comment: It is just a matter of avoiding duplication. I want to change the setting once in the DLL Project, and when I rebuild the other solutions that include the DLL Project, then the changes will happen without having to do the same changes in another App.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just remove the configSource attributes and then include all the content within the `<appSettings>` and `<connectionStrings>` elements

Comment: But I still need it to be 2 separate files, the first one referencing the second one who actually contains the configuration.

Comment: Q: "dll share the apps .config" A: Yes I know. Q: "why do you need the system.net section in another file?" A: That was just an example, for my full motivation see the newest comment I wrote to this question.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to get this to work using configSource

```
<configSections>
    <section name="Sites"
             type="Wap.Common.Configuration.SiteHandler, Wap.Common" />
</configSections>

<Sites configSource="Sites.Prod.config" />
```

and then in the external config file it needs to have the ?xml tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sites>
...
</Sites>
```

and then you need to set up the external config file to always copy to the output directory

Answer (score 6):

You should not put the system.net section inside the appSettings.config. The standard practice is one config node in a sub config file. I'm not even sure if it's possible to share the same file with different nodes.

You should create another file named perhaps system.net.config and place the entire body in there, the full

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="50"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Then in the App.config you will update the system.net to be

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement configSource="system.net.connectionManagement.config"/>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: `system.net` cannot declare a `configSource`.

Comment: updated answer to put configSource 1 level deeper, kind of pointless to DV an answer that is essentially correct but off from free hand coding...

Comment: It would be nice if it is was easier to find in the docs what can and can't be configSourced.