# Is it possible to move the container alias definitions into a separate file?

Tags: unity-container, app-config

I know a about the inclusion of config sections via configSource:

[Is there any way for an App.config file to reference another full config file? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487991/is-there-any-way-for-an-app-config-file-to-reference-another-full-config-file)

But this is not what I want.

I have a container configuration like this:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity" >

  <alias alias="IFoo" type="Namespace.Foo,Foo.Interface.dll"/>
  <alias alias="Foo" type="Namespace.Foo,Foo.dll"/>

  <container name="myContainer">
    <register type="IFoo" mapTo="Foo" /> 
  </container>
</unity>
```

Now I would like to move the alias definitions into an external file and reference it for he container. Something like this:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity" include="AliasDefinitions.config">

  <container name="myContainer" >
    <register type="IFoo" mapTo="Foo" /> 
  </container>
</unity>
```

Is there any way do this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a feature request,

http://unity.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Or you start a new discussion thread.

Unity is open source, so you can also implement this on your own.