# Deal with same namespace with different assembly

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have two different libraries, `Testlib1` and `Testlib2` in the same namespace, but I want them to use different `app.config` files.

Can I create one application with two different `app.config` files?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one app.config and run-time.  If you have assemblies with different app.config sections that are required, you need to transfer them to the main app.config file.

Answer (score 1):

The app.config file is for the executing application (usually an EXE file or web under IIS), not an assembly. If you want to share settings across multiple applications, see the answer in [Is there any way for an App.config file to reference another full config file? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487991/is-there-any-way-for-an-app-config-file-to-reference-another-full-config-file).

Answer (score 1):

The .NET configuration system is scoped by `AppDomain`, each AppDomain having its own config file.

It is therefore possible to have one application using more than one config file, if the applicaton creates additional AppDomains beside the one it starts in (see [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.6.1) for an example of such an application).

Designing and implementing a multiple-AppDomain application is not a trivial task, and if your only objective is separating the configuration of two libraries there are easier ways to do it (but not using multiple full config files).