# Using a settings file in a UserControl imported as .dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have created a simple "Wpf User Control Library" containing a UserControl (xaml with .cs code behind file) and a Settings file containing simple settings.
The Settings file is very much wanted in the final application, where users easily can change some settings in the settings file, hence I don't have to create a UI and logic for changing simple settings.

After Building the solution I have a .dll, a .pdb and the Settings file (.config) where the settings is easy readable.

Now, in the final application where the User Control .dll gets imported (Added as a reference) the usercontrol Works as intended and the settings that I had set in the Settings file is still working, but there is no Settings file (.config) in the Debug folder, hence, now place for the users to easily change the settings as desired.

How is that? And how can I ship the Settings file for the User Control along with the final application?

Best regards

Comment: Have you checked the properties of the config file? Is it set to copy always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you probably shouldn't be shipping things that haven't been built in Release mode.

Secondly, from my experience, an application can only have a single executable application configuration file loaded automatically by the .NET Configuration classes.

The correct way to handle this is to note the settings namespace that is generated under the applicationSettings sectionGroup for your DLL and have the user insert that into the main application executable .config file.

```
 <configuration>   
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
         <section name="My.UserControlAssembly.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    ...
    <applicationSettings>
      <My.UserControlAssembly.Properties.Settings>
        ...settings elements would go here...
       </My.UserControlAssembly.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Edit:** On further investigation, I found this article which tells you how to setup your own configSection so that you can reference multiple files. However, it does not specify whether this works with `ConfigurationManager` class automatically, so I would experiment with it and at worst, use the method I've described above.

[Is there any way for an App.config file to reference another full config file? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487991/is-there-any-way-for-an-app-config-file-to-reference-another-full-config-file)