# is it possible to get a value for an xml file from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller, sitecore

Hi I don't think this is possible but I have a value that needs to be used in multiple xml Config files for a Sitecore site. The problem is that the client only wants to update the value in one place.

for example if I have a file with a node with a value of

```
<settingexample name="ExampleGroup"/>
```

can I replace `ExampleGroup` with something that might link it to a settings xml file with the following setting

```
<setting name="ExampleProject.UserDomain" value="ExampleGroup"/>
```

That way all the xml nodes will match if I change it in a single place.

Comment: You could move the common config settings in an external file that you include in this one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480538/use-xml-includes-or-config-references-in-app-config-to-include-other-config-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487991/is-there-any-way-for-an-app-config-file-to-reference-another-full-config-file.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If you have a single value, why is it specified in multiple files? Why not just specify the value once? Can you be more specific in what you trying to achieve with clearer examples.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `<sc.variable>` like Sitecore does for the data folder.

Declare the variable:

```
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/data" />
```

And then use it:

```
<setting name="DebugFolder" value="$(dataFolder)/debug" />
```